# Unhandled exception at 0x00de1818 in 2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xcd7cbe10

Tags: c++

Here is my program
Contact.h

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#pragma once
class Contact
{
private:
char *Name;
char *Last;
int Phone;
char *Address;


public:
    Contact operator +(Contact NewVal);
    Contact(char *newName,char *newLastName,char *newAddress,int newPhone);
    Contact(void);
    ~Contact(void);




void SetName(char *newName);
void SetLastName(char *newLastName);
void SetAddress(char *newAddress);
void SetPhone(int newPhone);


char* Contact::GetLast(void);
char* Contact::GetAddress(void);
int Contact::GetPhone(void);
char* GetName(void);

};
```

Contact.cpp

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "Contact.h"


Contact::Contact(void)
{
}
Contact::Contact(char *newName,char *newLastName,char *newAddress,int newPhone)
{
    SetName(newName);
    SetLastName(newLastName);
    SetAddress(newAddress);
    SetPhone(newPhone);

}


Contact::~Contact(void)
{
}


void Contact::SetName(char *newName){
    Name=_strdup(newName);
}

void Contact::SetLastName(char *newLastName){
    Last=strdup(newLastName);
}

void Contact::SetAddress(char *newAddress){
    Address=strdup(newAddress);
}

void Contact::SetPhone(int newPhone){
    Phone=newPhone;
}

char* Contact::GetName(void)
{
    return Name;
}
char* Contact::GetLast(void)
{
    return Last;
}
char* Contact::GetAddress(void)
{
    return Address;
}
int Contact::GetPhone(void)
{
    return Phone;
}

Contact Contact::operator+(Contact NewVal)
{

            //strcat(this->Address,NewVal.Address);
            //strcat(this->Last,NewVal.Last);
            //strcat(this->Name,NewVal.Name);
            this->Phone=this->Phone+NewVal.Phone;
            sprintf(this->Address,"%s %s",this->Address,NewVal.Address);
            sprintf(this->Name,"%s %s",this->Name,NewVal.Name);
            sprintf(this->Last,"%s %s",this->Last,NewVal.Last);

            return *this;

}
```

Phonebook.h

```
#include "Contact.h"
#pragma once
class PhoneBook
{
private:
        Contact member[100];
        int ID;
public:

    PhoneBook(void);
    ~PhoneBook(void);
    Contact Search(char* newName);
    bool AddNewContact(char* NewName, char* NewLast, char* NewAddress,int NewPhone);
    void ShowContacts(void);
};
```

PhoneBook.Cpp

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "PhoneBook.h"


PhoneBook::PhoneBook(void)
{

}


PhoneBook::~PhoneBook(void)
{

}


Contact PhoneBook::Search(char* newName)
{

    return Contact();
}


bool PhoneBook::AddNewContact(char* NewName, char* NewLast, char* NewAddress,int NewPhone)
{
    ID=ID+1;
    member[ID].SetName(NewName);
    member[ID].SetLastName(NewLast);
    member[ID].SetAddress(NewAddress);
    member[ID].SetPhone(NewPhone);
    return true;
}


void PhoneBook::ShowContacts(void)
{
    for(int a=0;a<=ID;a++){
        cout<<"Name:"<<member[ID].GetName()<<endl<<"LastName:"<<member[ID].GetLast()<<endl<<"Address:"<<member[ID].GetAddress()<<endl<<"Phone:"<<member[ID].GetPhone()<<endl;
    }
}
```

After executing these lines I get access violation error(for SetName function)

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    PhoneBook mem;

    mem.AddNewContact("Bob","Jones","LA",100);


    return 0;
}
```

However this code works fine!!! it means Set functions in Contact.h file work without any problems but after adding the Phonebook class it won't work.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    PhoneBook mem;
    Contact no("Bob","Jones","LA",100);
    //mem.AddNewContact("Bob","Jones","LA",100);


    return 0;
}
```

I will be grateful if you can help me.

Comment: You'll likely get more help with your questions if you can provide a ***minimal**, complete, and verifiable* example.

Comment: Where do you initialise ID?

Comment: As a side note, why include <string> and <sstream> if you're going to use char* and not std::string and such?

Comment: dear Gary Sorry for long source code, but as you can see I want to show my problem clearly. Dear Steve Thanks for your tip it works fine. In addition I forgot to remove two both unused library.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for my mistake. I've forgotten to set a default value for ID variable.
Thanks Steve and Gray for your comments.